# Eclipse, Search for String inside method

Tags: eclipse

I often find myself having to scroll through methods spanning hundreds of lines to find a certain String.

Does anyone know if Eclipse provides a way to search for a specific String inside a method instead of the whole class?

Comment: If you can't find something you look for inside a class or method, it's a sign  that some refactoring is needed. Seriously, a method spanning hundreds of lines? How long are your classes?

Comment: That's not what I asked

Comment: I know, that's why I didn't post it as answer. It's just some well-ment advice. It would solve your problem though because as far as I know there is no possibility for doing what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that the Eclipse Emacs+ plugin can facilitate.  If you use the "narrow-to-region" function to limit the editor view to just your large method, you can then search the entire buffer for your string, and it would only be searching within the method.  When you're done limiting the region, you use "widen" to restore it.  This isn't changing the file, just changing your view of it.

Note that using the Emacs+ plugin doesn't require knowing anything about Emacs or eLisp.  The Eclipse Emacs+ plugin is just a large collection of useful functions that were inspired by usage patterns in Emacs.

That being said, the points about design issues in your classes are well-taken.  That probably doesn't help you right now, but they're still true.

Answer (score 0):

*Preferences* -> *Keys* -> *Show Selected Elements Only* -> *Binding*

Use that shortcut to focus on a single method.